# Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination

Tags: java, php, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I have a web application which runs on apache/PHP. In PHP, I have an activeMQ producer which writes some data into the queue. I'm using stomp client for this. For consumer, I'm using JMS + spring. I'm able to write the messages in PHP (i.e from producer). But while reading from my JMS consumer, I'm getting `Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format`.

Here is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
   xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
   http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="test"/>

<amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61613" />

<bean id="jmsConsumerConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory"
  p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="jmsFactory"/>

<jms:listener-container container-type="default" 
                        connection-factory="jmsConsumerConnectionFactory>
    <jms:listener destination="/topic/event" ref="jmsMessageListener" />
</jms:listener-container>

<amq:queue id="destination" physicalName="/topic/event"/> 
</beans>
```

Here is my message listener:

```
package test;

import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JmsMessageListener implements MessageListener {

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    System.out.println("msg recvd!");
  }

}
```

There was an example java program that came as part of apache activemq stomp examples which works fine. Here is the example:

```
package example;

import org.fusesource.stomp.jms.*;
import javax.jms.*;

class Listener {

    public static void main(String []args) throws JMSException {

        String user = env("ACTIVEMQ_USER", "admin");
        String password = env("ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD", "password");
        String host = env("ACTIVEMQ_HOST", "localhost");
        int port = Integer.parseInt(env("ACTIVEMQ_PORT", "61613"));
        String destination = arg(args, 0, "/topic/event");

        StompJmsConnectionFactory factory = new StompJmsConnectionFactory();
        factory.setBrokerURI("tcp://" + host + ":" + port);

        Connection connection = factory.createConnection(user, password);
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination dest = new StompJmsDestination(destination);

        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(dest);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long count = 1;
        System.out.println("Waiting for messages...");
    }
}
```

I read it in a forum that it it may happen when producer writes to a topic instead of a queue. If so, how do I handle it in spring?